# pubspec.yaml in flutter web or dartpad?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I don't have a really good computer that's why I can't run the android emulator on my pc. But, I still want to use flutter. Flutter web and dartpad work really well. But, if I want to add a custom font, image, or icon in my application then I have to use pubspec.yaml. I'm not sure how to access that file in the flutter web or dartpad. All I want to know is how to access that pubspec.yaml file. If you know then please consider helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to use a custom font (as you can't have `yaml` file). In your case, if you want to use a image, you can have it available somewhere like Google Drive, wherever you want to use it.

You can get it done with `Image.network`. And to add, I believe you can also use a custom icon by having it in the image format somewhere, say Google Drive and use it with `ImageIcon` and give the image using `NetworkImage`.

Get more information about `ImageIcon` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageIcon-class.html).